# How install packages in OpenBSD snapshot?

Tags: package-management, openbsd

If I install the ISO from: https://cloudflare.cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/snapshots/amd64/

Then how can I install packages? Or there is no pkg_add method in snapshots?

What do I need to do for example, if I want to install a firefox? compile it? how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install packages with `pkg_add` as usual, but use `-D snapshot` (or just `-D snap`) to make it look in the correct place on your selected mirror (the mirror listed in `/etc/installurl`).

So, to install Firefox, as root do:

```
pkg_add -D snapshot firefox
```

See also [`pkg_add(1)`](https://man.openbsd.org/pkg_add) and [`installurl(5)`](https://man.openbsd.org/installurl.5).

Note that you will need to keep your base system up to date to use the snapshot ports as they are rebuilt every once in a while, and the ports and base system should ideally be kept in sync.  The [`sysupgrade(8)`](https://man.openbsd.org/sysupgrade) utility makes this easy.

Comment: If I input "https://cloudflare.cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/snapshots/packages/amd64/" to the /etc/installurl and issue a "pkg_add firefox" then I only get an error message that "https://cloudflare.cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/snapshots/packages/amd64/6.3/packages/amd64: no such dir". - how do I tell pkg_add that it is doing a silly thing?

Comment: Basically you're over-specifying.  You only need: `https://cloudflare.cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD` in the installurl file.  OpenBSD figures out if you need snapshots or not (except for close to a release, like we are now, when you will need to specify: `pkg_add -D snap firefox`).  The reason for that, is the snapshots just before a release think they *are* the release, so they will look for "6.3" (for example) instead of "snapshots" when looking for packages.  See `man pkg_add` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq10.html#Patches:

> Upgrade your system to -current and use binary packages
>
> Binary packages for -current snapshots are rebuilt on a regular basis,
>   and these new packages will include any security fixes that were
>   committed. Simply call pkg_add(1) with the -u flag after picking a
>   mirror to get the new files.

Make sure to keep the base system updated as well.